# skype bot simulate real person

Tags: botframework, skype, skypedeveloper, skype-bots

I read about microsoft bot api. I know bots not working for some countries, bots hard to add in group chat(I can't do it), also bot can't read all messages in group chats

Is it possible to create "bot", which will be like a person? With register real skype account with login and password?

So it can be add to group chat without any country problems, and "bot" can read all messages and do some reaction on some "keywords"

Answer (score 1):

Bots can be added to group conversations if group conversations are enabled in the Channel Configuration:

[image]

However, the Bot Framework does not allow the Skype bot to receive all messages in the conversation.  This is by design:
[can-i-add-skype-bots-to-a-group-conversation](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34698/can-i-add-skype-bots-to-a-group-conversation)

> Bots in a group chat only receive messages directly addressed to them.

Comment: Yes I know about rule for read all messages, so I try find solution to read all messages. It can be not a bot, but simulate human account

Comment: You might be able to use this: https://evergreen.team/box-producs/konnektor.html I haven't tried it.